# Does upgrading a Linux kernel to the latest 64-bit change glibc?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Over at Linode we have been doing upgrades to take advantage of their new SSD drives. We are running on older Ubuntu 10.10 32-bit systems.

We have been changing our kernels from 32-bit to "latest 64-bit" in order to do the new upgrades. This has been working well so far (the 32-bit software we are running is happy to run in the 64-bit kernel), but I was wondering if this changes glibc or not. The only Linode I have where that might be a concern is one Linode where we build software with a C compiler and I didn't necessarily want to change the version of glibc used in making the build yet.

Yes, I know we should upgrade the actual distributions to a newer 64-bit Ubuntu, but that is a bigger project and not something we are ready to do just yet. So for the time being we just want to run using the latest 64-bit kernel, since it doesn't seem to be doing any harm. We are currently just concerned about the impact on glibc for creating builds from C source.

Of course if anybody know of any other downsides to running the 64-bit kernel please feel free to speak up!

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: No it doesn't. Basically a software package needs a set of libraries, including libc of the bitness of that software. You may run `ldd` on a binary and see the complete list of libraries it's linked against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

A 64-bit system:

```
 alex@rhyme ~/RPM $ ldd /bin/ls  
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffef200000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f4b7b9d8000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f4b7b7b0000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f4b7b5a8000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f4b7b398000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4b7afe8000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4b7bc30000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4b7ade0000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib64/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f4b7ab98000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f4b7a990000)
alex@rhyme ~/RPM $  sudo chroot hsh/chroot/ /bin/bash
[sudo] password for alex:
[root@rhyme /]#
```

but chrooted environment (used for build) is 32-bit:

```
[root@rhyme /]# ldd /bin/ls
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7752000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/libtinfo.so.5 (0xf76f8000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0xf76d0000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib/libcap.so.2 (0xf76c8000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib/libacl.so.1 (0xf76b8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7540000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7730000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/libpcre.so.3 (0xf74f8000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf74f0000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/libattr.so.1 (0xf74e8000)
[root@rhyme /]#
```

Notice the difference in ldd output. Versions of `coreutils` (and `ls`) are basically the same.

Using a 64-bit kernel may have a single downside, as I know. In 64-bit mode it requires slightly more memory for kernel itself and control structure (kernel code instructions are 64 bit). Other than that I do not notice any problem in such configuration.

BTW running a system where 32- and 64 binaries and libraries coexist *in a single system* is called multi-arch (in the example above there's no multi-arch, because the second system has its own, separate filesystem to which I've chrooted). As far as I know, both Debian and Ubuntu have a viable multi-arch support, and a single instance of `apt` may perfectly manage both 32- and 64-bits package sets.

So theoretically you can do a "slow migration", simply installing 64-bit libraries beside their 32-bit counterparts and replacing binaries 32- to 64-bit one by one. Certainly this wouldn't be a fastest way ;-) but it can be made almost seamless, no long downtimes or unexpected change of software version or behaviour. Certainly you mileage may vary, and you should carefully inspect your conditions, environment et cetera et cetera.